# Can a low-level type depend on a high-level abstraction?

Tags: c#, design, dependencies

**Context:**

This is for a library that reads some old games formats representing 3D models.

Let's call these low-level formats `PRM1`, `PRM2`, `PRM3` and `PRM4`.

- each of these formats contains the `position`, `origin` and `primitives` of a 3D model
- they have minor implementation differences but in the end produce the same type of content
- currently they all implement an `IModel` interface from which data is read to produce graphics

Now, I end up with duplicate methods in each of these types, they all do the same thing:

- `private GetMesh(IPolygon, ...)`
- `public GetMesh(...)` calls above method to produce a 3D model

So I thought, *why not ... ?*

- making a `Model` class that implements `IModel` directly, it would contain the whole mesh generation process since it's unique, effectively removing duplicate code
- `PRM1`, `PRM2`, `PRM3` and `PRM4` would then derive from `Model` and they would only contain the reading from the binary file itself through the `Model(Stream stream)` constructor entry point

While this sounds the way to go, it feels weird as now low-level types depend on a high-level type.

**Question:**

Is this a perfectly valid approach/pattern or is there something I am missing ?

Comment: Have you considered splitting the data out into a separate 'POCO' model instead of storing the data in the same classes which contain the behaviour to read that data?

Comment: No, actually I adopted this solution since it was the simplest approach I came up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just gave it a try and seems like it was a good move,

- I stripped out many redundant code
- locations where to look at are now reduced to  a single one
- concrete types only deal with the reading of data, base class does the transform
- rendering didn't break
- worked instantly
- more generalization
- etc ...

As a consequence I need some 'builders' to further abstract it but this is a good compromise IMO.